# How to fix connection time out error on Apache?

Tags: apache, centos, server

In my WordPress site, I keep getting this error some times, and some times the page loads OK:

Error log:

> 206.194.117.48 - - [06/Jan/2015:14:22:38 -0200] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.0" 200 1188 "http://www.example.com/?post_type=product" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"

What could be causing this? Any idea?

Edit:

Adding more info about these errors:

> 2015/01/06 16:04:05 [error] 1513#0: *296 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 186.194.237.48, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: `http://1.12.3.456:8080/`, host: "www.example.com"

Also, I may add, I created a fresh WordPress install and these errors reoccur. Other WordPress sites on the same server works just fine. I'm running CentOS 6.

Comment: I got a feeling that this is a server issue and not a WordPress issue.